# Calculate proportions of rows in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I have a problem that you hopefully can help with.

I have a dataframe with multiple columns that looks something like this:

```
education   experience  ExpenseA    ExpenseB    ExpenseC
uni         yes         3           2            5
uni         no          7           6            8
middle      yes         2           0            8
high        no          12          5            8
uni         yes         3           7            5
```

The Expenses A, B and C should add up to 10 per row, but often they don't because the data was not gathered correctly. For the rows where this is not the case, I want to take proportions.

```
The formula for this should be (cell value) / ((sum [ExpenseA] til [ExpenseC])/10)
```

example row two: total = 21 --> cells should be (value / 2.1)

How can I itterate this over all the rows for these specific columns?

Comment: What do you mean by ```sum of row x til z?```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need divide sum of columns with exclude first 2 columns selected by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df.iloc[:, 2:] = df.iloc[:, 2:].div(df.iloc[:, 2:].sum(axis=1).div(10), axis=0)
print (df)
  education experience  ExpenseA  ExpenseB  ExpenseC
0       uni        yes  3.000000  2.000000  5.000000
1       uni         no  3.333333  2.857143  3.809524
2    middle        yes  2.000000  0.000000  8.000000
3      high         no  4.800000  2.000000  3.200000
4       uni        yes  2.000000  4.666667  3.333333
```

Or sum columns with `Expense` substrings by [`DataFrame.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html):

```
df1 = df.filter(like='Expense')

df[df1.columns] = df1.div(df1.sum(axis=1).div(10), axis=0)
```